# How to access multiple class of a div in behat?

Tags: php, css, behat, mink

I have a div with two classes like this 
`<div class="class1 class2"> 
  <a href="/cart">TEXT</a>`.
 When i click on this class, i will redirect to one page. My question is how to execute the code in behat/mink.
I tried by this
 
`When I click element with class "button"` 
 but its not working.

```
           /**
           * @When /^I click element with class "([^"]*)"$/
           */
          public function iClickElementWithClass($class) {
            $locator = ".$class";
            $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $locator);

            if (null === $element) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate CSS selector: "%s"', $locator));
            }

            $element->click();
            $this->getSession()->wait(1000);
          }
```

Please find the error message(not navigating to the next page "/cart").

```
$ bin/behat features/cap_dutch_booking.feature
@javascript
Feature: Contact form Navigation and Submission
  In order to check booking form
  As an anonymous user
  I should to be able to submit the booking form

  Scenario: Submission of booking form with proper data # features\cap_dutch_booking.feature:8
    Given I am on homepage                              # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
    When I click "Opleidingen"                          # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    And I click "BIM"                                   # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    And I click "BISL┬« Foundation"                      # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    When I click element with id "edit-submit--3"       # FeatureContext::iClickElementWithId()
    And I should be on "/trainingen/bisl-foundation"    # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()
    When I click element with class "button"            # FeatureContext::iClickElementWithClass()
    And I should be on "/cart"                          # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()
      Current page is "/trainingen/bisl-foundation", but "/cart" expected.

1 scenario (1 failed)
8 steps (7 passed, 1 failed)
```

Comment: If you define what "not working" means, people might be able to help you with your question more easily. Is there an error message? Any logging output in the console?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the error message please look into that.

Comment: Welcome! I was just reviewing your post, so I can not help you with the issue itself. However, I've upvoted you so you get a bit more visibility.

Comment: I don't see any button, Try to click on the link ( a element).Is not a good practice to have a method that only clicks on a class, create a general method that click on any selector. In your case you should have something like: I click "a[href*=cart]"

Answer (score 1):

In your example you can use selectors like: .class1.class2

Try to remove $locator = ".$class"; and use .class1.class2 as parameter.
Also you should try to click on the link and not the div.

```
/**
 * @Then /^I click "(?P<selector>[^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClick($locator){
    $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $locator);

    if($element === null){
        throw new Exception("Element $locator not found");
    }

    $element->click();
}
```

add this method in FeatureContext or in the context where you keep your general methods, it should be the context that extends MinkContext.

And try one of these selector formats:

```css
a[href*=cart]
or
.class1.class2 a[href*=cart]
```

Use it like this in your test:

I click "a[href*=cart]"
or
I click ".class1.class2 a[href*=cart]"

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I get the link value. ?

Comment: remove $locator as i said and use $class variable in find method. The selector for the link should be: a[href*=cart]   or you can try .class1.class2 a[href*=cart]

Comment: Thank you for your response buddy. I have a confusion that where to use ur mentioned selectors in my code.?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle using multiple selectors.

`When I click element with xpath "//div[contains(@class,'button') and contains(@class,'btn2')]/a"`

```
/** Click on the element with the provided xpath query
 *
 * @Given /^I click on the element with xpath "([^"]*)"$/
 * @Given /^I click on element with xpath "([^"]*)"$/
 * @Given /^I click element with xpath "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iClickOnTheElementWithXPath($xpath)
{
    $session = $this->getMainContext()->getSession(); // get the mink session
    $element = $session->getPage()->find(
        'xpath',
        $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('xpath', $xpath)
    );

    // errors must not pass silently
    if (null === $element)
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate XPath: "%s"', $xpath));
    }

    // ok, let's click on it
    $element->click();

}
```